# Restarting a User-Input Function If User Inputs are Invalid

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, user-defined-functions

I am fairly new to Python, and programming.

I've been browsing around about how to do exactly this, restarting a user defined function if the inputs from the user are not valid, and most answers I have came across feature while loops, I cannot seem to correctly implement it into my code.

My code looks like this:

```
mchoices = input('Enter A or B or C or D or E or F: ')
def getRate(choices):
    if choices ==  'A':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[0]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'B':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[1]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'C':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[2]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'D':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[3]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'E':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[4]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'F':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[5]) + '%'
    else:
        return 'Please enter a valid option'
print(getRate(mchoices))
```

options is equal to a range (1,20) and radint(2,6), I don't think it's relevant to my problem but I am mentioning this in case you are confused about what it is. If it is relevant, I'll throw that part of the code in as well.

The main issue I am having is that towards the bottom, in the "else" part of my code, on top of having it return "Please enter a valid option" I would also like to have it restart the program so that the user can perform another input.

I expect the answer to do something with a while loop, which is fine, I just can't seem to do it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a method for getting user input.

```
$ cat askuser.py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# here's you getRate() method.

def getRate(choices):
    # I can only guess at what options is meant to be.
    options = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
    if choices ==  'A':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[0]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'B':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[1]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'C':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[2]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'D':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[3]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'E':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[4]) + '%'
    elif choices == 'F':
        return 'Rate = ' + str(options[5]) + '%'
    else:
        return 'Please enter a valid option'

def ask():
    user_input = 'None'
    while user_input not in ['A','B','C','D','E','F']:
        user_input = input("Enter A, B, C, D or E: ")
    return(user_input)

# voila!
print(getRate(ask())
```

Here what happens when you run this script:

```
$ ./askuser.py
Enter A, B, C, D or E: i
Enter A, B, C, D or E: 0
Enter A, B, C, D or E: XXXXX
Enter A, B, C, D or E: e
Enter A, B, C, D or E: E
Rate = 50%
```